# How to create variable with concatenation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, object, javascript-objects

I have very long code and want to simplify it. I don't think so we can use string concatination to create different variable name. Is there any other way.

```
If(Something){
    var a = some.Test1.x;
    var b = some.Test1.y;
    var c = some.Test1.z;
    var d = some.Test1.p;
}

If(SomethingElse){
    var a = some.Test2.x;
    var b = some.Test2.y;
    var c = some.Test2.z;
    var d = some.Test2.p;
}

If(OneMore){
    var a = some.Test3.x;
    var b = some.Test3.y;
    var c = some.Test3.z;
    var d = some.Test3.p;
}
```

May be create some function like this, i know this is not right but anything similar to that.

```
function test(s){
  a = some.s.x;
  b = some.s.y;
  c = some.s.z;
  d = some.s.p;
}
```

Comment: Note that you can replace `o.foo` with `o["foo"]` i.e. you can access the `foo` field / member of `o` either by literal or by string (`"foo"` may be a string)

Comment: This question is off-topic to SO and should be moved to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array-like syntax

```
function test(s) {
    var a,b,c,d;
    if (s === Something) {
        test = "Test1";
    }
    if (s === SomethingElse) {
        test = "Test2";
    }
    if (s === OneMore) {
        test = "Test3";
    }

    a = some[test].x;
    b = some[test].y;
    c = some[test].z;
    d = some[test].p;
}
```

This is a much improved version of the functionally equivalent, but never-to-be-used, eval syntax:

```
eval("a = some."+test+".x");
```

Comment: so if i have something like random.x.Test1.q i would do some.x[test].q as per your answer

Comment: @Nakib don't forget to handle `test === undefined` in this example

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(index){
  t = some["Test" + index];

  a = t.x;
  b = t.y;
  c = t.z;
  d = t.p;
}
```

and the execution:

```
test(1); test(2); test(3)
```